# When parsing a file using antlr 4, the tokens can either recognize the title of the whole string

Tags: antlr, antlr4, vcf-vcard

When I was trying to parse something like  vCard, when I set a token to read the first names as "FN" from the input, then I can't user getText(); method. Since the expression before the getText(); has to be the same with the expression from the start.

```
| Firstname         {System.out.println("First Name : " +$Letters.getText());}
| Letters           

Firstname: 'FN';
Letters: [A-Za-z0-9-]+;

vCard code:
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
PRODID:-//BBros.us llc//bvCard.com//EN
N:Nick;Jonas;;;
FN:Nick Jonas
```

The code will not work, since I use "$Letters.getText()" in the expression of Firstname. So I was wondering if there is a way in antlr, that I can read the first few letters, then print out the rest of the information. I don't know if getText(); is the only way. Since in the vCard code, I don't know how to read "FN" from "FN:Nick Jonas" and then print "Nick Jonas" afterwards.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely suere what and how you want to parse exactly but for the actual problem you coudl just do something like this:

```
Firstname Letters {System.out.println("First name: " + $Letters.getText());}
```

That is because I am assuming that xou want `Letters` to be matched after `Firstname` anyways because otherwise it wouldn't make sense (to me) to try to refere to the respective token from the `Firstname`-Alternative.

However if you are really looking into only matching a prefix and then printing out everything that comes afterwards you could do it like this (If you want to use Antlr instead of Regex for this):

```
Firstname content+=.* EOF
```

This will match `Firstname` and afterwards every lexer token that has been matched until the end of the file.
In order to make this work for every trailing input you can define a wildcard lexer rule at the bottom of your grammar that matches every input that hasn't been matched by the lexer rules before:

```
ANY: .+ ;
```

All the trailing tokens will be stored as an array (or as a list... not sure about this atm) in `content` whcih you can then refer to in order to reassemble the trailing input.

Comment: Is there a way that I can print out the end of the line or the end of the row rather then the end of the file?

Comment: simply replace `EOF` with another token (e.g. `\n`) and add an optional right recursion if needed